# changing the payment options in Admin does not change them on the front end

Tags: admin, payment-methods

Magento ver. 1.9.1.0.

I go to

> SYSTEM - CONFIGURATION - SALES - PAYMENT OPTIONS

...select the Current Configuration Scope to be **"Main website"**.

Set the SAVED CC Enabled to **NO**. Successufully save the change (it shows NO when I go out and log back in), delete all Cache and re-index but *it still shows up on the front end*.

Any guesses why that is?

Thanks,

Allysin

Comment: Are you running any additional caching layers? Could there be more configurations on a specific store scope overriding general configs? Are you using a custom checkout extension?

Comment: @Reid Blomquist I am still having this problem. I have NO additional caching layers, no custom checkout (I use the Porto theme). As far as the specific store scopes - I have Paypal and Saved CC on the main website and Saved CC on the other store. I just tried to add (Enable) the "Check / Money Order" option in the Default Config and then checked in the main store scope and it does say YES next to ENABLED but it does NOT show during the check-out (I even deleted ALL the Cache). What is interesting is - I just added the "Bank Transfer Payment" option and that DOES APPEAR in the check-out process

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your issue (with one caveat, i have a 1.9.3 install) and wasn't able to get the same results. I make the assumption that you are talking about the option to use a saved CC on the checkout. When I enable saved CC's I get this on the payments step in checkout:

[image]

And when I disable the option I'm getting this:

[image]

Which is the expected result. So in your case I'm leaning to what Reid suggested, you have a issue with caching on your site. The other option would be that you have an extension that is behaving badly. If you have a checkout extension, or something that will interact with payments, disable that first and then test  again with your store's caching disabled (System-> Cache Management in the admin).

For some more reading on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477967/how-do-remove-credit-card-save-payment-method-from-magento

Comment: I am still having this problem. I have NO additional caching layers, no custom checkout (I use the Porto theme). As far as the specific store scopes - I have Paypal and Saved CC on the main website and Saved CC on the other store. I just tried to add (Enable) the "Check / Money Order" option in the Default Config and then checked in the main store scope and it does say YES next to ENABLED but it does NOT show during the check-out (I even deleted ALL the Cache). What is interesting is - I just added the "Bank Transfer Payment" option and that DOES APPEAR in the check-out process

Comment: that points to an issue with the theme not correctly displaying all the different payment option in the template file. It's easy for a theme to ignore all the different options that are in the base template when they override it. Because this is a paid theme, have you tried reaching out to the developers with the issue? It's hard to work on here, even though i have access to the code for that theme, i can't post the code here as it's not my property. I'll look it over and see if i can figure out some of the file paths you can look in.

Comment: So i looked at the copy of the `Porto` theme and in the theme itself there isn't a override of the template that is displaying this functionality. On my 1.9 install the template is `frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml`. Could you put on template hints and see what what template is displaying the ill behaving feature? I still think this is a bad template, but if it's the core we could look at that code and see if someone has edited it from the core code.

Comment: oh, and take a look at the block that is being pulled in. For me it's `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods`. This would help to track down where the root of the problem is.